# Correct direction of block inserts of floyd rose tremolo?

Tags: electric-guitar

Recently I want to change the string of my guitar.
This is the first time I change a guitar with floyd rose tremolo.
After I loose the screw in the saddle, I found that the original 
set up is weird. Now I am not sure which is the correct way to insert those block inserts.
That is to say, I don't know whether the hole should point to the neck, or point the rear.
And I don't know whether the hole should be at top, or at bottom.
Please help!

[image: Block inserts]

Answer (score 3):

The hole needs to point to the rear and is at the bottom ( closest to the body of the guitar), as that is where the screw locates itself.

You'll see when it works right as it won't rest correctly the other way up.

Comment: I think I can put it any direction I want. My problem is, when I put it that way and insert the screw into the hole, there will be way too much space left and the string cannot be clamped. Do I need to insert the screw into the hole?

Comment: So what you are saying is with the screw fully in the clamp doesn't actually clamp the string?

Comment: @Ivan, that's really unusual, so you're saying that when you're inserting the screw in the hole, the thread of the screw is too short to clamp the block? Maybe changing your screws to new ones with a longer thread might help you. (I'll draw you picture of the right placement of the block, later today (sometimes a picture is better to explain things))

Comment: @Markus Thanks very much. I got the Jackson DK2M from Guitar Center. I am suspicious about that the tremolo in my guitar is modified by them. I noticed that some of the blocks are different, one of the blocks are stuck in the saddle and cannot be removed out, and some of the screws are longer.